# Upload file to git from html form

Tags: git, github, file-upload, bitbucket, gitlab

I would like some users of my website to upload files to a private git repo from an html form in my front-end.

So far I searched within the docs of all 3 major git provider: `github`, `gitlab` and `bitbucket`.

Each one of them offer an API to upload files which I would be glad to use, but here is the hiccup: the token to authorize access to API calls is not "repo based" rather it is "profile based" (1 token accessing all repos). This means I don't feel comfortable with using these calls right from my front-end, since they will leak my private token.

So, is there another way I didn't oversee ? or can this be accomplished with other git products ?

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** users are regular web users, meaning they will not create/connect git accounts... They just visit my website and submit a file for upload. I just don't want them to open Chrome Dev-tools and have my private token to mess around.

**EDIT: if you need to understand WHY then here is my answer** I just try to stay as lean as possible.

I have no PRE/POST-processing needs to do to the files before/after upload. Files need to end-up to a file versionning system (git). I just want to use the shortest path possible for the job and avoid creating a server just to proxy the file to git...

If by WHY you want to know "Why do I need it to fall into Git rather than S3" : because my system is tied to git for version control, plus submitted files need to be part of this version control ecosystem.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I agree with tremby: this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I am afraid there is no more to solve than "upload file to git". I just want to be able to let users upload a file to the same repo where my site lives... What else could I share with you that could help ?

Comment: The use case is exactly the same as any file-uploads but instead of having my own http server accepting POST requests, I'd like to leverage git providers one.

Comment: Why upload to git? Why not upload to a server?

Comment: To avoid having a server in the first place ? Think about it: why on earth would I need a server just to proxy a file upload ? if the question was "upload file to Amazon S3 from html" would it make more sense than "git" ? Why ? At the end of day, I just want my files to end-up in the git, I don't see any advantage/reason to make it transit to a server just because.